# Attributes against POCO objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have my POCO objects in a separate class, with each one implementing interfaces etc, which i believe perfectly fine to do with a POCO object.

I read all over the place that it is bad practice to add Entity Framework attributes to your POCO objects, so instead i use the fluent API.  Again i believe this to be correct.

I gather that if you need to apply a custom attribute against a POCO object, then this is not bad practice is it?  I guess its just like adding the object to an interface.  Or have i got it all completely wrong?

Using code first approach

Comment: It is not good or bad practice either way, it is simply a design choice. Everything you describe sounds perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

POCO objects have not dependencies on *external* libraries. These *dependencies* could come with the necessity to use external attributes or to derive from external class/interface.

So, nothing wrong with attributes in themselves, it's more about keeping your models clear from external dependencies. If you depend on external libraries in your models, you have to pull them with your models every time: e.g. when you decide to move your models in separate project, or when you decide to write Unit-tests that touch your models etc.

I agree with Ben Robinson that it is a design choice, but if you have chance to use clear models I think you should use it(with EF you have that chance). And if you were talking about your *own* custom attributes, then it's OK whatsoever.